# USB Driver for LGT8F328P Arduino clone

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

Where is the USB driver for LGT8F328P Arduino Nano clone downloaded from for Windows 10 64-bit?

When I plug in the LGT8F328P into USB, using IDE 1.8.13, it does not detect it. I think it is because there is no HOLTEK driver - wherever that is.

If you got this clone working on Windows 10 can you also mention what version of the Arduino IDE and what boards package (there's more than one for the LGT8F328P) you used and what Windows version you used.

The USB chip on the LGT8F328P clone board is a Holtek HT42B534 which is used as a  USB to serial interface

Comment: I don't have one of these, but I found a [tutorial](https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/lgt8f328p-lqfp32-boards) about them (though only in german), which used [this](https://github.com/dbuezas/lgt8fx) board package.

Comment: the USB is not in the 328p. as with ATmega, there must be an USB chip on board. I guess it is the CH340 as on clones with ATmega

Comment: @Juraj it uses a holtek for the USB to serial interface-I added a bit more info to the question regarding your comment

Comment: So you need a driver for the HT42B534 for Windows 10? Doesn't the OS detect the chip automatically? (I would expect this from a serious OS.) What does the hardware manager say?